# Need help fo finish Batch script?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

I would appreciate any help how to start or anything.

I just found out that there is a tool 'ImageMagick' who can command-line Auto resize images. Based on that knowledge I think that is smarter to do the following:

Folder structure:

1. C:\TEST --> subfolders -->  import, export
2. import  --> subfolders -->  We do not know the exact name of the folder, it can be anything!
3. export  --> subfolders -->  files from 'import'

When I put 'X' number of folders (each folder contains, a 'X' number of pictures) to 'import' I want to:

> 1. Copy first 'X' folder in 'import' (and all images inside) to 'export' -> resize to 400x300px and rename as '1a'
> 2. Copy first 'X' folder in 'import' (and all images inside) to 'export' -> resize to 200x150px and rename as '1b'
>
>    *. Under the assumption that there are ten pictures copied in first
>      'X' folder in 'export'...
>       It will look like this - 1a,1b, 2a,2b, 3a,3b ... 10a,10b

When finish the first 'X' folder...start again, until it reaches the end of 'X' folder in 'import'.

---

Example #:    This is just an assumption, the names and numbers of files and folders we dont no!

Folder structure:

1. C:\TEST --> subfolders -->  import, export
2. import  --> subfolders -->  f1, e7, DD   --> we have three folders
3. export  --> subfolders -->  f1, e7, DD

   1. Resize all pictures in 'C:\TEST\import\f1' to 'C:\TEST\export\f1\1a'
   2. Resize all pictures in 'C:\TEST\import\f1' to 'C:\TEST\export\f1\1b'
   3. Resize all pictures in 'C:\TEST\import\e7' to 'C:\TEST\export\e7\1a'
   4. Resize all pictures in 'C:\TEST\import\e7' to 'C:\TEST\export\e7\1b'
   5. Resize all pictures in 'C:\TEST\import\DD' to 'C:\TEST\export\DD\1a'
   6. Resize all pictures in 'C:\TEST\import\DD' to 'C:\TEST\export\DD\1b'

---

> ImageMagick syntax for resize in command-line:

mogrify -resize 400x300 source file

mogrify -resize 400x300 C:\picture_name.jpg

I found batch script on their website http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16486 maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Here's how to write a batch script to do what you need done (in Python):
Save it as runMogrify.py

```
import os
import string
import fnmatch

source = "c:\\TEST\\import"
target = "c:\\TEST\\export"

def mogrify(parmSource, parmTarget):
    mkdirList = []
    copyList = []
    mogrifyList = []

    mkdirList.append('mkdir "' + parmTarget + '"')

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk (parmSource):
        # print dirpath, dirnames, filenames
        for (index,file) in enumerate(sorted(filenames)):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file.lower(), '*.jpg') or \
               fnmatch.fnmatch(file.lower(), '*.gif') or \
               fnmatch.fnmatch(file.lower(), '*.bmp'):
                sourceFDirPathFile = dirpath + "\\" + file

                targetFDirPath     = os.path.join (parmTarget, dirpath[1+len (parmSource):])
                targetADirPathFile = targetFDirPath + "\\" + str(index+1) + "a" + os.path.splitext(file)[1]
                targetBDirPathFile = targetFDirPath + "\\" + str(index+1) + "b" + os.path.splitext(file)[1]

                if 'mkdir "' + targetFDirPath + '"' not in mkdirList:
                    mkdirList.append('mkdir "' + targetFDirPath + '"')

                copyList.append('copy "' + sourceFDirPathFile + '" "' + targetADirPathFile + '"')
                copyList.append('copy "' + sourceFDirPathFile + '" "' + targetBDirPathFile + '"')

                mogrifyList.append('mogrify -resize 400x300 "' + targetADirPathFile + '"')
                mogrifyList.append('mogrify -resize 200x150 "' + targetBDirPathFile + '"')

    return mkdirList, copyList, mogrifyList

def main():
    mkdirList, copyList, mogrifyList = mogrify(source, target)

    f = open('RUNMOGRIFY.BAT', 'w')
    f.writelines( list("%s\n" % item for item in mkdirList  ) )
    f.writelines( list("%s\n" % item for item in copyList   ) )
    f.writelines( list("%s\n" % item for item in mogrifyList) )
    f.close()

if __name__=="__main__": main()
```

And, here's the resulting batch file (RUNMOGRIFY.BAT) after I ran the Python script above
on a test directory similar to yours:

```
mkdir "c:\TEST\export"
mkdir "c:\TEST\export\folder1"
mkdir "c:\TEST\export\folder2"
mkdir "c:\TEST\export\folder3"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder1\a.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder1\1a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder1\a.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder1\1b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder1\b.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder1\2a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder1\b.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder1\2b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder1\c.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder1\3a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder1\c.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder1\3b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder2\a.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder2\1a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder2\a.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder2\1b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder2\b.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder2\2a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder2\b.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder2\2b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder2\c.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder2\3a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder2\c.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder2\3b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder3\a.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder3\1a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder3\a.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder3\1b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder3\b.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder3\2a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder3\b.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder3\2b.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder3\c.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder3\3a.jpg"
copy "c:\TEST\import\folder3\c.jpg" "c:\TEST\export\folder3\3b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder1\1a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder1\1b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder1\2a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder1\2b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder1\3a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder1\3b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder2\1a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder2\1b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder2\2a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder2\2b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder2\3a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder2\3b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder3\1a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder3\1b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder3\2a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder3\2b.jpg"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "c:\TEST\export\folder3\3a.jpg"
mogrify -resize 200x150 "c:\TEST\export\folder3\3b.jpg"
```

Comment: Also, what is the extension on your files (if a *.jpg file does not exist in the import subfolder, it will not create an export folder hierarchy for an empty import subfolder)

Comment: Change it back to c:\\TEST\\import and C:\\TEST\\export. Are there any jpg files inside the subfolders in import? What does your import folder tree look like?

Comment: When i run MOGRIFY.BAT to process images....Loop continues indefinitely..until i press ctrl+c to stop.

Comment: Import folder tree: folderX, folderX, folderX........in every 'folderX' are 'X' numbers of jpg,bmp or gif images. Here's how it should look FINISHED 'export' folder tree: 
"export" -> "folderX -> 1a.jpg, 1b.jpg...2a.JPG, 2b.JPG...3a.gif,3b.gif......Xa.jpg,Xb.jpg"...next dir..
"folderX -> 1a.jpg, 1b.jpg...2a.bmp, 2b.bmp...3a.GIF,3b.GIF......Xa.jpg,Xb.jpg" ....and so on. Every picture in 'import' is resize to 1a.extension & 1b.extension (jpg,gif or bmp)....If some xxx.jpg picture in 'import' exist it will look like 1a.jpg & 1b.jpg. Every picture retains its extension. I hope I explained nicely?

Comment: Of all members here,only You and Aacini....especially You have tried to REALY HELP! I wish you all the best, even if you do not find a solution. I think this problem is not too complicated as it seems as I described it to difficult.

Comment: OK, found the problem. When mogrify gets called from mogrify.bat, it calls not the mogrify ImageMagick utility, but the mogrify.bat batch file. I changed the python code above to output a batch RUNMOGRIFY.BAT

Comment: I also added a DOS pause after every mogrify command so you can go statement by statement and make sure it does what it's supposed to. Press enter to go to the next statement.

Comment: Replace your mogrify.py Python file with runmogrify.py and copy paste the new python code above into runmogrify.py. It will generate runmogrify.bat. Make sure that you have a C:\import folder and leave C:\\import as is in the Python code above.

Comment: Thank. I need to 'export' look like this......."export" -> "folderX -> 1a.jpg, 1b.jpg...2a.JPG, 2b.JPG...3a.gif,3b.gif......Xa.jpg,Xb.jpg"..........not....1a & 1b are not folders........1a and 1b are pictures.

Comment: Changed the script per your specifications. Try it again with the new Python code.

Comment: Added condition so that redundant mkdirs do not appear.

Comment: I can't believe....script working perfectly!!! Thank you Dragos Toader. THANK YOU!!!!